# How to put specific options on top of dropdown list in rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to show some specific options in a dropdown list on top and should sort other options in alpha order. For example if the list is,

```
["CANADA", "PORTUGAL", "AUSTRALIA", "USA", "BRAZIL"]
```

I need to show the dropdown list as (usa and portugal as per requirements on top of the list and others in alpha order.)

```
["USA", "PORTUGAL", "AUSTRALIA", "BRAZIL", "CANADA"]
```

Comment: do you want to show all countries or just the country in your array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list = [2,1,3,4]

list = [list.delete(4)] + list.sort

puts list.inspect

# [4, 1, 2, 3]
```